# unusual language text clustering / classification

Tags: nlp, classification, cluster-analysis, data-mining, text-classification

Briefing:
What would be your approach to clustering similar text from unusual language.

Details:
I'm scraping a classified ads website trying to group similar ads(same product). The text has often misspelling, written in 2 languages (a bit of kind of 1ee7) and some text written phonetically in different alphabet (ex. Diànshì for 电视 or velosiped for велосипед) or different dialect.

Then how would you proceed to manage such an unpredictable input?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how large dataset you have. You could construct a similarity matrix for the data objects using some string distance metric like edit distance or Jaccard with n-grams. There are many clustering algorithms that can cluster almost any kind of data based on distance matrix. For example, Agglomerative clustering or Density Peaks  could be used. Both have typically O(N<sup>2</sup>) time complexity, so may not be feasible for large datasets.

Personally, I've used a faster (than O(N<sup>2</sup>)) variant of Density Peaks for large ( > 500,000) string datasets, and it was able to cluster the data mostly according to the language also. But the method is not public yet.